# Cache reflection information

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, reflection

What will be faster, access a `MethodInfo` via reflection:

```
var info = instance.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, 
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | 
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

every time i need to invoke a method, or should i store the `MethodInfo` in a `Dictionary<..., MethodInfo>` and than access the method information over the key of the dictionary?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it should be obvious.. Definitely storing method info in memory is faster than getting it everytime.

Comment: [Measure it](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: If calling more than a couple of times cache it. Reflection is slooow

Comment: [Horses...](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). I assume you've tried and compared both and somewhat not satisfied with results. Consider adding results of your comparison to your post. (along with both versions of the code).

Answer (score 0):

Caching reflection informations is always better because when you retrieve them via builtin API, it lock a global dictionary to provide an unique instance. This can be bad with high usage of them + multithreading. Pre-cache can help.